# Is phone call history available on OS X?

Tags: macos, call

For example, we know messages are saved in `~/Library/Messages/chat.db` however where are calls saved? Is there a folder or file?

Comment: What app are you using under OS X to make calls with?

Comment: @user3439894 FaceTime takes the calls I think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found my history at:

~/Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB/CallHistory.storedata

Comment: What is a `storedata` file? How do I read it?

Comment: It seems to be a sqlite database.  I read it with an app called [sqlitebrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23117831/what-is-the-difference-between-sqlite-and-storedata

Answer (score 3):

if you want to be able to decode the destination phone/facetime numbers stored in `storedata`, there are currently two solutions available:

- [Original solution](https://github.com/n0fate/OS-X-Continuity) in Python
- Faster [Golang implementation](https://github.com/rusq/osx-callhistory-decryptor) based on the original solution

Both allow to decrypt the addressee number, but the latter is available as executable files for different platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Just a follow up to @Pukeko answer; I wanted to decode the ZADDRESS field in my Objective-C app.  It took me a while to work out, so thought I'd share the code in case it helps someone else.

Based on https://github.com/n0fate/OS-X-Continuity as linked by Pukeko

I included this: https://github.com/indisoluble/AesGcm in my project

```
NSString *base64Key = @""; //Password found in Keychain for "Call History User Data Key"

NSData *key = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:base64Key options:0];

NSData *iv = [zAddr subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0x10, 0x10)];
NSData *data = [zAddr subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0x20, zAddr.length - 0x20)];
NSData *tag = [zAddr subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0x10)];

IAGCipheredData *cipheredData = [[IAGCipheredData alloc] initWithCipheredData:data authenticationTag:tag];

NSData *plainData = [IAGAesGcm plainDataByAuthenticatedDecryptingCipheredData:cipheredData
                                              withAdditionalAuthenticatedData:[NSData data]
                                                         initializationVector:iv
                                                                          key:key
                                                                        error:nil];

return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:plainData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can view a list of recent calls in the Phone app, just tap "Recents" at the bottom.

I would imagine that this list is saved in an iTunes backup of your device. There are a number of apps for Mac and Windows that allow you to explore the backup file and extract quite a number of the files. I do not know if the list of recent calls is saved.

On occasion I have used iExplore for viewing the contents of the backup. There are others out there that do similar things.

Comment: I want to be able to save them programatically. This won't work.