# Access full FaceTime call history?

Tags: iphone, mac, facetime

I am wondering where FaceTime call history is stored on my Macbook? I am running Big Sur 11.4 and Facetime Version 5.0 (3080).

When I try to view my call history it only shows the last 100 entries or so. However, I know that more than 100 are stored because I can see farther back by deleting more recent entries. So I am wondering if there is a better way to see old calls than to delete newer ones. I also know that this is technically possible because software like iMazing is able to do this.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is phone call history available on OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224137/is-phone-call-history-available-on-os-x). Couldn't flag it as there's a bounty